# Members/pointers inside different classes don't change values

Tags: c++, pointers, member

I have a program with two classes. In the fileTxt class i declare x & y values and the relative pointers. Then i go to the Byz class were i declare delta x & y values to sum to the x & y values previously declared. Then the program go back to fileTxt class were i print the new x & y values.
1) Why the x & y values inside Byz class before dx/dy sum are different from x & y declaration?
2) Why the new x & y values are the declared and not the x/y inside byz + dx/dy values?
main.cpp

```
#include "fileTxt.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fileTxt _fileTxt;
    _fileTxt.elab();

    return 0;
}
```

fileTxt.cpp

```
#include "fileTxt.h"
#include "byz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

fileTxt::fileTxt()
{

}

fileTxt::~fileTxt()
{
    delete[] pX;
    pX=nullptr;
    delete[] pY;
    pY=nullptr;
}

void fileTxt::elab()
{
    x=12.34;
    y=56.78;
    std::cout << "x declaration: " << *pX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y declaration: " << *pY << std::endl;

    Byz _Byz;
    _Byz.leggiByz();

    std::cout << "\nnew x value: " << *pX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "new y value: " << *pY << std::endl;
}
```

fileTxt.h

```
#ifndef FILETXT_H
#define FILETXT_H
#include <string>

class fileTxt
{
    public:
        fileTxt();
        virtual ~fileTxt();

        void elab();

    private:

        float x=0.0;
        float y=0.0;
        float *pX=&x;
        float *pY=&y;
};

#endif // FILETXT_H
```

byz.cpp

```
#include "byz.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Byz::Byz()
{

}

Byz::~Byz()
{

}

void Byz::leggiByz()
{
    dx=8.123;
    dy=9.456;

    std::cout << "\nx inside byz - before: " << *pX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y inside byz - before: " << *pY << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\ndx: " << dx << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dy: " << dy << std::endl;
    *pX=*pX+dx;
    *pY=*pY+dy;
    std::cout << "\nx inside byz + dx: " << *pX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y inside byz + dy: " << *pY << std::endl;
}
```

byz.h

```
#ifndef BYZ_H
#define BYZ_H
#include <string>

class Byz
{
    public:
        Byz();
        virtual ~Byz();

        void leggiByz();

    private:
        float dx=0.0;
        float dy=0.0;
        float x=0.0;
        float *pX=&x;
        float y=0.0;
        float *pY=&y;
};

#endif // BYZ_H
```

x declaration: 12.34
y declaration: 56.78

x inside byz - before: 0.0
y inside byz - before: 0.0

dx: 8.123
dy: 9.456

x inside byz + dx: 8.123
y inside byz + dy: 9.456

new x value: 12.34
new y value: 56.78

Comment: In the `fileTxt` destructor, why do you `delete[]` the pointers `px` and `py`? You don't do `new[]` anywhere? Doing `delete` or `delete[]` using pointer that doesn't point to memory allocated with `new` or `new[]` is wrong.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that member variables are local to the current object. Unrelated objects have unrelated member variables. It doesn't matter if two unrelated classes have member variables with the same name, the classes, and their instances, are unrelated.

Comment: As a side note, why are you storing pointers to member variables like that?  Unless those pointers end up pointing to other variables later they can be removed and IMHO, your code will become more legible.

Comment: Lastly, in `leggiByz` you print the values of the *uninitialized* member variable `x` and `y`. *And* you use them in other expressions. Uninitialized member variables have an *indeterminate* value, and using them in any way (except to initialize them) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Some programmer dude 'in fileTxt': Code corrected ---- 'in leggiByz': do you mean float x,y; in .h file? I put them to 0.0 and x/y inside byz - before: 0.0  Code corrected

Comment: @UKMonkey do you mean is better to pass x & y to leggiByz() instead of using pointers and also use a RETURN method?

Comment: You should write a `set` function to change the values of member variables, not pointers.

Comment: @MassimoD.N.  why do you need to pass them in as function arguments at all?  They're member variables - meaning that all functions that are a member have access.  Rather than all the *pX stuff, you just assign x.